# Does not render the component at the press of a button React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the next code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Opciones from './Opciones'

import './TableColumnas.scss';

const TableColumnas  = ({data, distribuida}) => {


const addOption = (i, j) => {
  data.tiempo_comida[i].columnas[j].push("Hello");
  console.log(data);

}

const addColumn = (i, j) => {
  data.tiempo_comida[i].columnas.push([]);
  console.log(data);
}

const change = (e, i, j, k) => { //e: event
  if(k){
  data.tiempo_comida[i].columnas[j][k] = e.target.value;
  }else{
  data.tiempo_comida[i].columnas[j][0] = e.target.value;
  }
}

return(
  <>
    <table className="content-table">
      <tbody>
      <>
        {data.tiempo_comida.map((grupo_comidas,i)=>(
        <>
          <tr key={i}>
            <p>{grupo_comidas.nombre_tiempo.label}</p>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {grupo_comidas.columnas.map((comidas, j)=>(
              <>
              <td key={j}>
                {(comidas.length !== 0) ?
                comidas.map((comida,k)=>(
                  <>
                  {console.log(comida)}
                  <div className="container" key={k}>
                  <div className="input">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Text" defaultValue={comida} onChange={(e) => {change(e, i, j, k)}}/>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </>
                ))
                :
                <>
                  <div className="container">
                  <div className="input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Text" onChange={(e) => {change(e, i, j)}}/>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </>
                  }
                  <button onClick={()=>{addOption(i, j)}}>
                  +option
                  </button>
                </td>
              </>
            ))}
            <button onClick={()=>{addColumn(i)}}>
              +column
            </button>
          </tr>
        </>
        ))}
      </>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </>
  )
  }

export default TableColumnas;
```

And the data received in the prop are as follows

```
var tiempo_comida = [{
    nombre_tiempo:{
        name: "desayuno",
        label: "Desayuno",
        image: "desayuno",
        color: "#EDC940"
    },
    columnas:[[],['jugo','cafe'],['tortillas','pan']]
},{
    nombre_tiempo:{
        name: "colacion1",
        label: "Colación",
        image: "colacion1",
        color: "#54BDE9"
    },
    columnas:[['huevo','tocino','queso'],['jugo','cafe'],['tortillas','pan']]
},{
    nombre_tiempo:{
        name: "comida",
        label: "Comida",
        image: "comida",
        color: "#72BEB2"
    },
    columnas:[['huevo','tocino','queso'],['jugo','cafe'],['tortillas','pan']]
},{
    nombre_tiempo:{
        name: "colacion2",
        label: "Colación",
        image: "colacion2",
        color: "#4868AC"
    },
    columnas:[['huevo','tocino','queso'],['jugo','cafe'],['tortillas','pan']]
},{
    nombre_tiempo:{
        name: "cena",
        label: "Cena",
        image: "cena",
        color: "#9563A3"
    },
    columnas:[['huevo','tocino','queso'],['jugo','cafe'],['tortillas','pan']]
},
]
```

If I press the buttons to add an option or a column and take out a data console.log gives me the values with the Hello added, but the screen does not increase.

The objective is that when pressing the button an element is added to the Array and therefore a new input is added

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot mutate props directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only), you must update them in the parent.

`addOption`, `addColumn` and `change` functions should be in the parent and passed to this component as props.

Comment: One solution could be to save the prop in a state and from the state to do everything?

Comment: I put the data directly in the component, without passing it as a prop, and still without increasing options or columns